# Python: Using list comprehensions to filter a list by a list of substrings

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension, substring

I think this is a simple question, so I'll just go straight to an example.

Given these two lists:

```
x = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bc', 'c', 'ac']
y = ['a', 'b']
```

How do I write a list comprehension to filter list x in such a way that the result would be:

```
result = ['c']
```

I want a list comprehension that excludes any partial matches of the strings in y to the strings in x.  For example, 'a' in y would match 'a', 'ab', 'abc', and 'ac' in x.

This comprehension only matches entire strings: `result = [r for r in x if r not in y]`

If this has already been asked I'll gladly accept a link to a previous answer.  That said, I haven't found one on SO yet.

Comment: OP already knew how to use a list comprehension to apply a predicate to each element of `x`, so the only remaining question is how to write that predicate. The condition we want to check is whether any element of y is `in` the given element of `x`. That's already well-covered territory; see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
result = [r for r in x if all(z not in r for z in y)]
```

Or [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
result = [r for r in x if not any(z in r for z in y)]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) built-in.

```
>>> x = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bc', 'c', 'ac']
>>> y = ['a', 'b']
>>> [r for r in x if not any(s in r for s in y)]
['c']
```

`s in r` does the partial match you want, `for s in y` checks all elements of `y`, and `any` is true if there was *any* match.  Then we just invert it.

This is quadratic, O(`len(x) * len(y)`).  If `y` is long, it may be more efficient to synthesize a regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> yy = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(s) for s in y))
>>> [r for r in x if not yy.search(r)]
['c']
```

which *should* be merely O(`len(x) + len(y)`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the length of your `y` what the best approach is, if it contains a lot of elements I would convert it to a set and check if any item in x has an intersection (one common character) with it:

```
y = set(y)
[item for item in x if not y.intersection(item)]
```

Comment: This assumes `y` only contains strings of length 1, which is the case in the example but wasn't specified.

Comment: Yes, if it contains more characters this would definitly fail to work, maybe I took the OPs example to literally. But on the other hand if `y` only contains single letters it's much faster. :-)

Comment: Yep, in my actual project this is being used to filter a list of urls by substrings.